# iOS PUSH notification type options? Alert vs Banner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push

I have read through posts on here suggesting that the only way to make PUSH notifications appear as an alert instead of a banner is for the individual end user to change the `Alert Style` in the `Notifications` section of the app's `Settings`.  What puzzles me is that there are apps out there that default to `Alerts` style without having to do this.

Is there a way to programatically set `Alerts` style through a dialog upon initial launch?  I don't mind asking the user to confirm in a dialog. I just know since other apps don't require the user to manually go into settings to change the alert style, there has to be a different method of doing this...

I've got the following -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of such apps, so we could look into that?

Comment: CSR Racing for sure...

Comment: http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1803/ra0k.png
This is the default notification settings that I got when I installed it. Anyway - I don't think that it's possible to set those.

Comment: Strange.  CSR automatically was set to "Alert" on mine.  So was Skype.

Comment: Is it possible that you've installed both of those before and have changed the settings to Alert, then removed the apps and have just now installed them again?

Comment: No way...  Especially Skype.  Tried it on my GF's phone too and it's automatically set to alert.  I have iOS5 and she has iOS7.

Comment: Just downloaded CSR Racing onto my device. I have never heard of CSR Racing let alone installed it. When I allowed pushes in the app it is automatically set to Banners in the settings panel. It is not possible to force the type of alert the user sees. See my answer below for more explanation.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app only has the rights to check for notification settings, you can never set or change notification types for a user.

When you query notification types the options are as follows

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIRemoteNotificationType) {
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 1 << 3,
}
```

All you can find out from querying the push settings is wether or not the user has enabled alerts but not how they are displayed (banner vs alert).

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible,you can't do it.

You can use this line to query the current settings for notification style:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType* enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

You can check the enabledTypes and then instruct the user to change the notification style in the settings.

Comment: You can't actually check for alert style. Just if they allow alerts of any style. So you can't prompt a user to change their alert style based on the enabled types.