# ios change lock screen notification type form banner to alert type

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In one of my project i want to change lock screen push notification which display as banner but i want to change it to alert type notification ,alert type notification works fine when phone is not locked but when phone is lock and push arrives i want to show same alert like before phone lock same on phone lock screen..in one of app it shows push alert when phone is lock.here is screen shot

[image]

same alert i want to show in my app when app receives push notification and phone is lock. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the default notification alert style via programming.

You can set from your iPhone or iPad

1. Open the Settings app from the iPhone home screen.
2. Tap the 'Notifications' settings pane.
3. Tap the name of the app you want to configure the alert style for.
4. Choose popup alerts, banner alerts, or no alerts.

You can check the answer for more help : [iOS PUSH notification type options? Alert vs Banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185886/ios-push-notification-type-options-alert-vs-banner)

See One More answer : [How to change notification type from Banner to Alert in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449539/how-to-change-notification-type-from-banner-to-alert-in-ios8)

> I don't believe there is any way to programmatically force the system
>   to display your notification as an alert rather than as a banner.
>   Looking over the [documentation for
>   `UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/category)
>   and for
>   [`UIUserNotificationSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIUserNotificationType),
>   I don't see anything that would allow you to specify that you want an
>   alert instead of a banner.
>
> It's up to the user to adjust their notification settings for your app
>   - I would leave it to them to decide how they want to receive notifications.

Comment: i already set alert style of notification, but when phone is locked at that time by default it shows as a banner style but in setting i set as a alert.

Comment: I know it is not possible to set, In my image you show that it is show alert when device is locked, so i am very confused how they implement that, because this is live application.